# sorting files using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, concurrency, synchronization

I was given an assignment to write all ordered contents of given files into a result.txt. At first, the filenames are split into different Arraylists where each file contains a label in a format #n/N where N is the total number of files. e.g.

British explorer James Clark Ross led the first
expedition to reach the north magnetic pole
#001/004

from a file 1831-06-01.txt

The problem with my code is that it has written in order 1,4,2,3 respectively. However, the result must be in order 1,2,3,4. This may be due to a lack of synchronization. Nonetheless, I am still struggling to fix the problem.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class PopThread implements Runnable {
    ArrayList<String> fileList; 
    
    public PopThread(ArrayList<String> fileList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("running\n");

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("fileList: " + fileList);

        ArrayList<String> sortedFileList = sortFiles(fileList);

        File resultFile = new File("result.txt");

        for (String filename : sortedFileList) {
            Writer w1 = new Writer(filename, resultFile);
            Thread t = new Thread(w1);
            t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            t.start();
        }

        long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        //System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (stopTime - startTime));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> readFiles(String filename) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            File myObj = new File(filename);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(myObj);
            
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                list.add(s.next());
            }
            
            s.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public int getNumber(String filename) {
        String lastLine = "";
        String sCurrentLine;
        
        int identifier_integer = -1;
        
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lastLine = sCurrentLine;
            }
            
            String identifier_number = lastLine.substring(1,4);
            identifier_integer = Integer.parseInt(identifier_number);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return identifier_integer;
        
    }
    
    public ArrayList<String> sortFiles(ArrayList<String> listFileName) {
        int i = listFileName.size();
        boolean sorted = false;
        
        while ( (i > 1)  &&  (!(sorted)) ) {
            sorted = true;
            
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                if ( getNumber(listFileName.get(j-1)) > getNumber(listFileName.get(j)) ) {
                    String temp = listFileName.get(j-1);
                    listFileName.set(j-1, listFileName.get(j));
                    listFileName.set(j, temp);
                    
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
            i--;
        }
        
        return listFileName;
    }

}

class Writer implements Runnable {
    String filename;
    File resultFile;

    public Writer(String filename, File resultFile) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.resultFile = resultFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String content;
        content = readFromFile(filename);
        writeToFile(resultFile, content);
    }

    private static void writeToFile(File resultFile, String content) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultFile, true));
            writer.write(content);
            //writer.write("file content written");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static String readFromFile(String filename) {
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            String text;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(text);
                content.append("\n");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content.toString();
    }

}


public class q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> filesOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        filesOne.add("1831-06-01.txt");
        filesOne.add("2003-08-27.txt");

        ArrayList<String> filesTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        filesTwo.add("1961-04-12.txt");
        filesTwo.add("1972-12-11.txt");

        PopThread popRunnableOne = new PopThread(filesOne);
        PopThread popRunnableTwo = new PopThread(filesTwo);

        Thread threadOne = new Thread(popRunnableOne);
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(popRunnableTwo);

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();
        try {
            threadOne.join();
            threadTwo.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
}
```

( NOTE: The class q4 cannot be altered)

Comment: The task as stated is impossible without writing bizarre code. The JVM does not guarantee that `threadOne` starts before `threadTwo` does (even though `threadOne` is started first). So you'd have to code a global counter, and have PopThread use this global counter (as the 'first' PopThread object is guaranteed to be constructed before the other). At this point I'd just talk to your prof and explain that files is a dumb thing to use multithreading on, given that generally the disk is the bottleneck and not the CPU. This is just a silly, overly convoluted way that will be __slower__.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Hi there, I know it is weird, it would be easier with a single thread. Now, I have no idea what to do?

Comment: This question has some of the same problems as your previous question about the same topic. You don't say clearly what you are trying to do. Based on our chat on the previous question here's what I _think_ you are trying to do: (1) You were given the `q4` class, and you are assigned to create the `PopThread` class. (2) The program is expected to concatenate the contents of the four named files to its standard output. (3) The four files must be concatenated in ascending date order according to the dates in their filenames. The fact that "each file contains a label in a format #n/N" is...

Comment: ...not part of the problem definition. Your program isn't expected to parse the files. Those labels are just meant to help you see whether or not the files were output in the correct order. Am I right? Is all of that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment is horrible. You have my sympathy.

---

Your two threads will have to communicate with each other. Each thread will have to know, what is the filename that the *other* thread wants to output next. And, they will have to take turns. Each thread needs to loop:

1. While the date on my next file is less than or equal to the date on the other thread's next file, output my next file,
2. Tell the other thread, "it's your turn,"
3. If I have no more files, then exit (return from the `run()` method), otherwise, wait for the other thread to tell me it's *my* turn again,
4. Go back to step 1.

Having to take turns is the worst part of the assignment. Any time you find yourself needing to make threads take turns doing something—any time you need to make threads do things in a particular order—that's a clear sign that *all* of the things should be done by a single thread.

---

The only way threads can communicate is through shared variables. Your instructor has done you a *huge* disservice by telling you not to modify the `q4` class. That prevents you from passing any shared objects in to your `PopThread` implementation through its constructor.

The only other way your two threads can share any variables is by making the variables `static`.  Forcing you to use `static` is the second worst part of the assignment. If you go on to study software engineering, you will learn that `static` is an [*anti-pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). Programs that use `static` variables are *brittle* (i.e., hard to modify), and they are hard to test.

Forcing you to use static variables also will make your threads do extra work to figure out who is who. Normally, I would do something like this so that each thread would automatically know which state is its own, and which belongs to the other guy:

```java
class SharedState { ... }

class PopThread {
    public PopThread(
        SharedState myState,
        SharedState otherThreadState,
        ArrayList<String> fileList
    ) {
        this.myState = myState;
        this.otherGuyState = otherThreadState;
        this.fileList = fileList;
        ...initialize this.myState...
    }
    ...
}

class q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedState stateOne = new SharedState();
        SharedState stateTwo = new SharedState();
        PopThread popRunnableOne = new PopThread(stateOne, stateTwo, filesOne);
        PopThread popRunnableTwo = new PopThread(stateTwo, stateOne, filesTwo);
        ...
    }
}
```

The best way I can think of with static variables would be to have an array of two `SharedState`, and have the threads use an `AtomicInteger` to each assign themself one of the two array slots:

```java
class PopThread {
    static SharedState[] state = new SharedState [2];
    static AtomicInteger nextStateIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public PopThread(
        SharedState myState,
        SharedState otherThreadState,
        ArrayList<String> fileList
    ) {
        myStateIndex = nextStateIndex.getAndIncrement();
        otherGuysStateIndex = myStateIndex ^ 1;
        this.fileList = fileList;
        ...initialize state[myStateIndex]...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks u for your advice, I appreciated your help. I have a hard time understanding the purpose of sharedState() class? what does it store?

Comment: @BOB, The `SharedState` is where each thread would keeps any information that the other thread needs to see. E.g., the this-is-the-next-filename-that-I-want-to-output variable. Also, it is where you keep whatever objects you choose to use so that one thread can await its turn, and the other thread can notify it that "it's your turn."

Comment: Is it possible to pass an array from thread two to thread one and sort the files and write contents to result.txt on only thread one?

Comment: @BOB, sure, you can put anything you want in the `SharedState`, but perhaps you should ask your instructor whether you are _allowed_ to use only one thread. Once you have a means to pass data from one thread to the other, you could literally do _all_ of the work in just one of the two threads, but your instructor might consider that to be cheating.

Comment: I would like to try this method. However, How would you kill thread two once thread one finishes the task?

Comment: @BOB, A Java thread kills itself by returning from its `run()` method.

Comment: right now, both threads would write the files. I only want one to write and other to do nothing, How would I do that?

Comment: @BOB, I've given you some ideas, but the more I drill down into the details, the more it feels like I'm doing your homework for you. I don't want to cross that line. FYI: The questions you are asking me now—how to make a function that writes four files, how to make a function that does nothing—feel like intro to programming 101. If you are in a class that is asking you to write multi-threaded code, then you may be in deeper water than you realize.